# Reasons of delayed damage signs to AMOLED touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, damage

I had the misfortune of dropping my cellphone (couple of feet). It was working perfectly right away but throughout the day the screen started displaying a darker spot in one corner that overtime expanded to the upper half of the screen, the remaining became discolored turning to a purplish hue and becoming less and less responsive to touch and finally the day after was completely black.
It seems im not the only one seeing this happening after a fall.
Why there can be such a delay to complete screen failure?

Comment: Possibly spreading environmental contamination or oxidation?

Comment: Depends in how they have it wired for multiplexing, but I could see some of the circuitry being damaged. Then, when it is used over time, the damage causes failure of other circuitry (over-current/voltage), which may damage other circuitry...etc.

Comment: My first thought was that it might be a problem with voltage regulation for the screen, but it was just what popped in my mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You broke the seal between the two layers of glass in the AMOLED display, which allowed oxygen and/or moisture to infiltrate into the display over time, rendering the organic compounds useless. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED#Disadvantages) for details.

Comment: I thought that AMOLED screens did not have any liquid, just an organic compound deposited to the base layer...

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: You're right. I missed the specific screen type mentioned in the title. Fixed.

Comment: it would make sense given the first sign appeared on the corner that hit the ground, so much for calling it unbreakable in the ads